# Determine stability of the origin using the Lyapunov function $V(x,y) = ax^4 + bx^2 + cxy + dy^2$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the dynamical system
$$ \dot{x} = y \quad \dot{y} = y -x^3$$
determine the stability of the origin using the Lyapunov function $V(x,y) = ax^4 + bx^2 +cxy + dy^2$.

I have that $V(0,0) = 0$. Now, I need to show that $V(x, y) > 0$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. If $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, $V(x,y) >0$. I am having a difficulty figuring out the case of $x$ and $y$ having opposite signs. I considered imposing restrictions on $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ and considering some smaller open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ perhaps $D = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$, but I kept confusing myself. Any help would be appreciated.

As a note, the book my have intended to say that $a,b,c,d > 0$ (usually the case), but they did not explicitly mention this. The particular book I am using is occasionally scant on details.

EDIT: The answer key notes that I am supposed to conclude that $\dot{V} > 0$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. As mentioned in the comments, normally I would find values for the parameters such that $\dot{V} \leq 0$ and then proceed, with that information, to show that the particular $V$ is positive definite. This must not be what the author intended given the confirmed solution.

Comment: For questions like this, you're supposed to find *specific* values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ such that $V$ becomes a Lyapunov function for the given system (so you don't just need that $V$ is positive definite, but also that $\dot V$ is negative definite).

Comment: By the way, are you sure you copied the system correctly? As it's written now, the origin is obviously **un**stable (since the linearization is $\dot x=y$, $\dot y=x$).

Comment: Yes, that is the correct system, and yes, the origin is unstable. I am supposed to conclude, given the specific $V$, that $\dot{V} > 0$ for all $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and that the origin is unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the term $x^3y$, it is obviously necessary $d=2a$. Let $a=\frac14$,
$d=\frac12$.
Consider the function
$$
V(x,y)= \frac14 x^4+b x^2 +cxy+ \frac12 y^2.
$$
Its derivative is
$$
\dot V= \left(x^3+2bx+cy\right)y+\left(cx+y\right)(y-x^3)
$$
$$
=x^3y+2bxy+cy^2+cxy+y^2-cx^4-x^3y
$$
$$
=(c+1) y^2+(2b+c)xy-cx^4.
$$
Let $b=-\frac12c$. Then
$$
\dot V= (c+1)y^2-cx^4.
$$
Obviously, if $c\in (-1;0)$, then $\dot V$ is negative definite. Consider the quadratic part of $V$:
$$
b x^2 +cxy+ \frac12 y^2= -\frac12c x^2+cxy+ \frac12 y^2.
$$
It is easy to see that $c=-\frac12$ gives us a positive definite $V$.

Comment: Why is it easy to see that $-\frac{1}{2}$ gives a positive definite $V$? Also, the origin is unstable, so how is it that $V$ can be positive definite while $\dot{V}$ is negative definite?

Comment: If $c=-\frac12$, $\dot V=\frac12 y^2+\frac12 x^4$ is positive definite.

Comment: @TheSenate Applying Sylvester's criterion, one obtains $\det\left( \begin{array}{rr}  1/4 & -1/4 \\ -1/4 & 1/2\end{array} \right)=1/16>0$. Or you can use $\frac14 x^2-\frac12 xy+\frac12 y^2=\frac14(x-y)^2+\frac14y^2$

Comment: Oh, I see. You wrote “it’s easy to see that $V$ is positive definite,” but I think you meant, “it’s easy to see that $\dot{V}$ is positive definite,” regarding $c= -\frac{1}{2}$. Correct?

Comment: @TheSenate I meant both. Having taught linear algebra for some years, I can determine by eye the definiteness of quadratic forms :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Apologies if I made some errors in our communication. I need a day to rest before my exam.